# Python3 os.urandom() for password salts

Tags: python, csv, passwords, salt

I want to generate a password salt with `os.urandom()`.
And then create a hash with:

```
hashed_pw = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), salt.encode(), 300000)
```

This works fine, but I want to also store the hash and salt to login after I quit the program.
I currently use csv files store the password/salt.
If I now read the data for the username with a `csv.DictReader` the salt is of type str.
If now compare the hashes it doesn't work because the hash algorithm expects a byte.
If I use `salt.encode()` its now a byte but different from the original byte.
How can I fix this?
I only get this to work if I just generate a random string and save into the csv and then encode both in the hashing function.
But I think using `os.urandom` for the salt is more secure.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: You don't have a simple program to store / retrieve the csv so we need to do some guessing, but you could do a bin2ascii encoding of the salt when you write the csv and the reverse when reading.

Comment: Also, its better to be explicit about encodings. `passwrod.encode()` assumes that your default encoding is always the same. `password.encode(encoding="utf-8")` solves that.

Comment: @tdelaney FYI, in Python since 3.2, *encoding* defaults to `utf-8`, but explicit is better than implicit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.hex()` on a `bytes` object to get a `str` value suitable for a CSV, and `.fromhex()` on that `str` to get `bytes` again:

```py
import os
import hashlib

password = "mysecurepassword"
salt = os.urandom(10) # returns bytes
hashed_pw = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256','password'.encode(),salt,300000)
hexpw = hashed_pw.hex()
hexsalt = salt.hex()
print(hexpw,hexsalt) # suitable for CSV

pw2 = bytes.fromhex(hexpw)
salt2 = bytes.fromhex(hexsalt)

assert(hashed_pw == pw2)
assert(salt == salt2)
```

Output:

```
e6134156ba833d22c30d4e387103505727232f74905b3a3119bd4b6d121cbff4 97181907f5f1a5b61d8c
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great